# interact with a console program using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I'm currently making a chess web-based app. Now that I want to add in the stockfish chess engine which I will have to interact with in the command line. I've searched the internet and there's the child_process exe related to Node.js. I know how to use it, but only when it is compiled with Node (for example "node file.js" in the command line) but then i don't know how to call that from my main javascript file which contains the chessboard and stuff.
Is there a way to do it (if that's even possible) or you may suggest me another way to do it please :D ?

Comment: You can improve your question a bit by adding some env details. What chess engine is?

Comment: oh i use stockfish

Comment: Almost in any way - you should run the child process with `exec` and read std-out. In perfect condition, you can access the child process using IPC. But it's hard to tell exactly w/o knowing what engine you use.

Digg in : https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Comment: I googled for you like `{whatever} npm`. Good luck with chess :)

Comment: thanks for spending time tho, I think i'll spend some more time on that

Answer (score 1):

As you using `stockfish` - It's not necessary to be CLI version.

Here is a pure JavaScript implementation:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/stockfish

Comment: oh maybe this is a better solution for this, thank you